# Images and links broken when accessing wordpress site on a lan

Tags: wordpress

I having some challenges when access my wordpress site on a different within the same LAN.  I'm using xampp and my ip instead of localhost.

The links & images are all broken only texts are shown. How to resolve this?

Comment: What do you see in the console? image paths are relative?

Comment: update your question according to the following guidelines - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The image path are absolute.